# Accessing the Text of Dynamically Created Textfields in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have created textfield Dynamically i need to access the text entered in the textfield. Please help me to do this.

```
 -(void)createHHDynamicFieldForYValue:(int )yVal
  {

NSString *lblStr=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[healthyHeartFieldsAry objectAtIndex:tagHHCount] objectForKey:@"TestName"]];

dynamicHealthyHeartLbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,yVal,278,45)];
dynamicHealthyHeartLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
dynamicHealthyHeartLbl.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:17/255.0 green:61/255.0 blue:83/255.0 alpha:1];
dynamicHealthyHeartLbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
dynamicHealthyHeartLbl.text=lblStr;
dynamicHealthyHeartLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
[healthyHeartScrollView addSubview:dynamicHealthyHeartLbl];
[dynamicHealthyHeartLbl release];
[lblStr release];



dynamicHealthyHeartImgVw=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(375, yVal, 278,kTxtImgHgVal)];
dynamicHealthyHeartImgVw.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"birth_date.png"];
dynamicHealthyHeartImgVw.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[healthyHeartScrollView addSubview:dynamicHealthyHeartImgVw];
[dynamicHealthyHeartImgVw release];



dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(380,yVal,278,kTxtImgHgVal )];
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:17/255.0 green:61/255.0 blue:83/255.0 alpha:1];
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.delegate = self;
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.placeholder=[[healthyHeartFieldsAry objectAtIndex:tagHHCount] objectForKey:@"TestName"];
dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.tag=tagHHCount;
[healthyHeartScrollView addSubview:dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld];
[dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld release];


[healthyHeart_TxtFldAry addObject:dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld];

[dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld release];


tagHHCount++;


}

int YVal=35;
tagHHCount=0;
NSLog(@"healthyHeartFieldsAry Count %d",[healthyHeartFieldsAry count]);
for (int i=0; i<[healthyHeartFieldsAry count]; i++)
{
    [self createHHDynamicFieldForYValue:YVal];
    YVal=YVal+80;
}
```

In TextField Did End Editing

```
    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        if(enteredHealthyHeart)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<[healthyHeart_TxtFldAry count];i++)
            {
                if(textField == [healthyHeart_TxtFldAry objectAtIndex:i])
                {
                    getHHTag=textField.tag;
                    //              UITextField *tempTxtFld=[healthyHeart_TxtFldAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag];

                dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld=[healthyHeart_TxtFldAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag];
                if([dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.text length]>0)
                {
                    NSString *tempStr=dynamicHealthyHeartTxtFld.text;
                    NSLog(@"tempStr %@",tempStr);
                    if(![self checkForDecimalValue:tempStr])
                    {
                    Custom_Alert *alert=[[Custom_Alert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please Enter Numeric Values" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];

                }
                else
                {

                    if(([tempStr intValue] >= [[[healthyHeartFieldsAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag] objectForKey:@"MinVal"] intValue])&&([tempStr intValue] <= [[[healthyHeartFieldsAry objectAtIndex:getHHTag]objectForKey:@"MaxVal"]intValue]))
                    {
                        NSLog(@"validation Succcess!!!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Custom_Alert *alert=[[Custom_Alert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please check the Details" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alert show];
                        [alert release];
                    }


                }
            }


            [textField resignFirstResponder];
            //return YES;

        }
    }

}
```

}

I want to know how to access the textField Text. How to identify which textfield text is entered. Any help ???

Comment: You can know that by using the tag value of text field

Comment: that tag is also dynamic.How can i identify text is belongs to which textfield?

Comment: well i guess you got your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have declared the textfield in your `interface` file, you can access it via it's instance variable:

```
NSLog(@"text from textfield: %@", dynamicTextField.text);
```

or via the property:

```
NSLog(@"text from textfield: %@", self.dynamicTextField.text);
```

But if you create many textfields in a `for` loop do like this:

while creating the textField, say:

```
dynamicTextField.tag = x;
```

where "x" is the incremented integer of your loop.

now, to access it's value, say:

```
for(UITextField *texter in self.view.subviews)
   if(texter.tag == 1)//or any other tag number you have specified on creating the textField
       NSLog(@"textfield with tag 1 contains text: %@", texter.text);
```

You just have to remember which tag number was assigned to the desired textfield

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a reference to the textField its just a property

`textField.text` will return whatever is currently typed into the textField.

Answer (score 0):

you have created the property of **UITextFiled** Obejct then you can access it `txtFiled.text` and `[txtFiled text]` both you can use.

Answer (score 0):

In this method `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` the argument is the textfield in which the user is typed.

Use `textField.text` for taking the data from the textfield and `textField.tag` for taking the tag (for identifying the textfield).

```
NSlog(@"%@",textField.text); //print the text content
NSlog(@"%d",textField.tag); //print the tag
```